# How do I add bootstrap.min.css to my Django project

Tags: django-rest-framework

I'm trying to customise the look of the DRF tutorial API by following this - https://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/browsable-api/?q=base.html#the-browsable-api.

If I use a web address in the api.html href here, it works:

```
{% extends "rest_framework/base.html" %}

{% block bootstrap_theme %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://bootswatch.com/5/vapor/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css">
{% endblock %}
```

If I download bootstrap.min.css, where should I put it, and what should the href path be?
Wherever I try at the moment, I get a `Not Found:` error in the server logs.

Here's my TEMPLATES dictionary from settings.py:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'snippets', 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

And my directory structure:

```
.
└── pastebin
    ├── db.sqlite3
    ├── manage.py
    ├── pastebin
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── __pycache__
    │   ├── asgi.py
    │   ├── pathtest.py
    │   ├── settings.py
    │   ├── urls.py
    │   └── wsgi.py
    └── snippets
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── __pycache__
        ├── admin.py
        ├── apps.py
        ├── migrations
        │   ├── 0001_initial.py
        │   ├── 0002_snippet_highlighted.py
        │   ├── __init__.py
        │   └── __pycache__
        ├── models.py
        ├── serializers.py
        ├── templates
        │   └── rest_framework
        │       └── api.html
        ├── tests.py
        ├── urls.py
        └── views.py
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I appear to have found a way. I'd be interested to know if this is the correct way.

I added a static directory with the downloaded css file in it:

```
.
└── pastebin
    ├── db.sqlite3
    ├── manage.py
    ├── pastebin
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── __pycache__
    │   ├── asgi.py
    │   ├── pathtest.py
    │   ├── settings.py
    │   ├── urls.py
    │   └── wsgi.py
    ├── snippets
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── __pycache__
    │   ├── admin.py
    │   ├── apps.py
    │   ├── migrations
    │   │   ├── 0001_initial.py
    │   │   ├── 0002_snippet_highlighted.py
    │   │   ├── __init__.py
    │   │   └── __pycache__
    │   ├── models.py
    │   ├── serializers.py
    │   ├── templates
    │   │   └── rest_framework
    │   │       └── api.html
    │   ├── tests.py
    │   ├── urls.py
    │   └── views.py
    └── static
        └── bootstrap.css
```

I updated the settings.py file with this:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / "static",
    ]
```

And the href in api.html like so:

```
{% extends "rest_framework/base.html" %}

{% block bootstrap_theme %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/bootstrap.css" type="text/css">
{% endblock %}
```

According to the docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/static-files/#configuring-static-files), when running the development server with `python3 manage.py runserver` the serving of this static file is being handled automatically.